# SpriteKit Backdrop PNG with Alpha showing black

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit, png

I have a `Spritekit` game made in Swift and when it's game over, I have a backdrop that's a `png` file that has an alpha value of 0.5ish (so its see-through). I made it in photoshop.

I use it to dull the game detail and place the scorecard over the top of it.

When I use it on my iPhone 6 plus running iOS 9.2 it works great, dulls the details and displays the scorecard... but when I run it on the simulator running iOS 9.2 or an iPhone 5C running iOS 8.4, it just appears black... covering the whole game screen...

It's declared like this:

```
    //alpha'sd png created in photoshop. approx. 0.3 alpha
    let backdrop = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Background_Alpha") 

    backdrop.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
    backdrop.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height)
    backdrop.name = "ScoreScreen"
    backdrop.zPosition = Layer.UIBackground.rawValue
    worldNode.addChild(backdrop)
```

and called like this:

```
    backdrop.alpha = 0
    let drop = SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(kAnimDelay)
    drop.timingMode = .EaseInEaseOut
    backdrop.runAction(SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.waitForDuration(kAnimDelay),
        drop
        ]))
```

Here is a screen shot form the simulator... but as I mentioned, it also happens on my iPhone 5C with 8.4...

[image: simulator screenshot]

The black should be a see-through blue ray, allowing the player to still see the game in the background, but not as vividly...

Any ideas why?

Comment: is the backdrop sknode or skspritenode? Did u try the alpha property of that node ?

Comment: It's an `SKSpriteNode`. Well it works on my 6+ so the alpha values are fine. The only thing I can think is there's something SpriteKit has for iOS 9 that wasn't in iOS 8... But all the code for that image is above. I figured the simulator just doesn't show alpha...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852102/serious-spritekit-uicolor-bug-on-iphone-5s) has an answer that says:

> According to the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SpriteKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/SKColor):
>
> Sprite Kit works only with solid colors. For best results, use the
> preset colors provided by the platform class or a custom color defined
> in the RGBA device color space

Whether that's still true, I don't know, but what I did instead of using an `alpha'd png` is to just create it from scratch using Spritekit and call it as follow:

```
    let backdrop = SKSpriteNode(color: 
                          SKColor(red: 29.0/255.0, 
                                green: 113.0/255.0, 
                                 blue: 149.0/255.0, 
                                alpha: 0.3),         //set alpha here
                                 size: size)

    backdrop.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)
    backdrop.name = "ScoreScreen"
    backdrop.zPosition = Layer.UIBackground.rawValue
    worldNode.addChild(backdrop)                     //add it to world

    //because I set the alpha in the SKSpriteNode,
    //I can still animate it in from alpha=0 to alpha=0.3:

    backdrop.alpha = 0
    let drop = SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(kAnimDelay)
    drop.timingMode = .EaseInEaseOut
    backdrop.runAction(SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.waitForDuration(kAnimDelay),
        drop
        ]))
```

This works now and displays a transparent sprite over the whole game at the game over screen to dull scene. Also a lot more efficient given the project no longer needs a whole png image to be stored.

I would still be interested in knowing why it doesn't work how I originally had it, but this is a solution nether the less.

Comment: a lot has changed in sprite kit from 8 to 9,  and a lot of bugs were fixed,  as for the simulator,  lets face it, it is a simulator,  you can't trust it 100%